# Python WebServer Creator UI Bug

Tags: python, flask, tkinter

My program i a web server creator with UI and I want to get the data from `Text` class in tkinter package and return it on a flask server but the Program shows double Windows and the flask server shows nothing.

```py
try:
    import sys
    import platform
    from flask import Flask
    from typing import List
    from time import strftime
    from datetime import date
    from subprocess import run
    from webbrowser import open
    from consts import CONST_COLORS
    from builtins import (str , int ,Exception)
    from tkinter import font
    from tkinter.tix import Button
    from tkinter.ttk import (Label , Entry , Notebook , Frame , Combobox)
    from tkinter.__init__ import (Tk , StringVar , Text)
    from tkinter.constants import (RAISED , FLAT , BOTH , CENTER , RIDGE , END)
    from http.server import (BaseHTTPRequestHandler , HTTPServer)

except:
    raise Exception


class WebServerCreationClass:
    def __init__(self) -> str:
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title("WebServer Creator")
        self.root.geometry("{0}x{1}".format(350 , 550))
        self.root.resizable(0 , 0)
        self.root.config(bg = CONST_COLORS[0][0] , cursor = None)
        self.tabDashboard = Notebook(master = self.root)
        self.firstTab = Frame(self.tabDashboard)
        self.secondTab = Frame(self.tabDashboard)
        self.outputTab = Frame(self.tabDashboard)
        self.svEntryPort = StringVar(self.firstTab)
        self.svOptionChs = StringVar(self.firstTab)
        self.flaskServer = Flask(__name__)
        self.defaultHost : str = "localhost"
        self.defaultPort : int = 8080
        self.getTime = strftime("%H:%M:%S %p")
        self.optionChoices : List[str] = [
            "Python http Server" ,
            "Django Server" ,
            "Flask Server" ,
            "Nginx" ,
            "Ngrok" ,
            "Default (localhost)"
        ]
        self.svEntryPort.set(self.defaultPort)
        self.svOptionChs.set(self.optionChoices[2])

        @self.flaskServer.route('/')
        def ClickEventButton():
            newText = self.textToTemplate.get(1.0 , END)
            return f"{newText}"

        def ButtonEventClicker():
            ClickEventButton()
            try:
                self.flaskServer.debug = True
                self.flaskServer.run(
                    host = "0.0.0.0" ,
                    port = 8080
                )
            except Exception:
                pass


        self.tabDashboard.add(
            child = self.firstTab ,
            text = "Config"
        )

        self.tabDashboard.add(
            child = self.secondTab ,
            text = "Mode"
        )

        self.tabDashboard.add(
            child = self.outputTab ,
            text = "Output/Terminal"
        )

        self.firstTabLabel = Label(
            master = self.firstTab ,
            text = None ,
            background = CONST_COLORS[0][0] ,
            width = 82
        )

        self.labelPort = Label(
            master = self.firstTab ,
            text = "Port :" ,
            background = CONST_COLORS[0][0] ,
            foreground = CONST_COLORS[0][1] ,
            font = ("Vani" , 22 , font.BOLD) ,
            relief = FLAT
        )

        self.labelServer = Label(
            master = self.firstTab ,
            text = "Server :" ,
            background = CONST_COLORS[0][0] ,
            foreground = CONST_COLORS[0][1] ,
            font = ("Vani" , 22 , font.BOLD) ,
            relief = FLAT
        )

        self.secondTabLabel = Label(
            master = self.secondTab ,
            text = None ,
            background = CONST_COLORS[0][0] ,
            width = 82
        )

        self.outputtabLabel = Label(
            master = self.outputTab ,
            text = None ,
            background = CONST_COLORS[0][0] ,
            width = 82
        )

        self.entryPort = Entry(
            master = self.firstTab ,
            textvariable = self.svEntryPort ,
            background = CONST_COLORS[0][1] ,
            foreground = CONST_COLORS[0][0] ,
            font = ("Vani" , 13 , font.BOLD) ,
            justify = CENTER ,
            width = 25
        )

        self.optionSelect = Combobox(
            master = self.firstTab ,
            textvariable = self.svOptionChs ,
            values = self.optionChoices ,
            font = ("Vani" , 13 , font.BOLD) ,
            justify = CENTER
        )

        self.htmlLabel = Label(
            master = self.firstTab ,
            text = "HTML" ,
            background = CONST_COLORS[0][0] ,
            foreground = CONST_COLORS[0][1] ,
            font = ("Vani" , 22 , font.BOLD) ,
            relief = RIDGE ,
            borderwidth = 8 ,
            width = 12 ,
            justify = CENTER
        )

        self.textToTemplate = Text(
            master = self.firstTab ,
            width = 36
        )

        self.outputTerminal = Text(
            master = self.outputTab ,
            width = 43 , 
            font = ("Courier" , 15 , font.BOLD) ,
            background = CONST_COLORS[0][3] ,
            foreground = CONST_COLORS[0][2]
        )

        self.outputTerminal.insert(1.0 , f"Date : {date.today()}\nTime : {self.getTime}")

        self.createServerButton = Button(
            master = self.firstTab ,
            text = "Create Server" ,
            command = ButtonEventClicker ,
            bg = CONST_COLORS[0][4] ,
            fg = CONST_COLORS[0][1] ,
            font = ("Vani" , 15 , font.BOLD) ,
            relief = RAISED ,
            bd = 5
        )

        self.tabDashboard.pack(
            expand = 1 ,
            fill = BOTH
        )

        self.firstTabLabel.place(
            x = 0 ,
            y = 0 ,
            height = 600
        )

        self.secondTabLabel.place(
            x = 0 ,
            y = 0 ,
            height = 600
        )

        self.outputtabLabel.place(
            x = 0 ,
            y = 0 ,
            height = 600
        )

        self.labelPort.place(
            x = 0 ,
            y = 0
        )

        self.labelServer.place(
            x = 0 ,
            y = 60
        )

        self.entryPort.place(
            x = 90 ,
            y = 8
        )

        self.optionSelect.place(
            x = 120 ,
            y = 68
        )

        self.createServerButton.place(
            x = 100 ,
            y = 450
        )

        self.htmlLabel.place(
            x = 78 ,
            y = 110
        )

        self.textToTemplate.place(
            x = 25 ,
            y = 160 ,
            height = 275
        )

        self.outputTerminal.place(
            x = 0 ,
            y = 0 ,
            height = 524
        )

        self.htmlLabel.configure(anchor = CENTER)

        self.root.mainloop()



# if (platform.system()[0].upper() == "W"): 
#     WebServerCreationClass()
# else:
#     sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    WebServerCreationClass()
```

and this is `consts.py`

```py
from typing import (Dict , List)
from builtins import (int , str)


CONST_COLORS : List[Dict[int , str]] = [
    {
        0 : "#1D2934" ,
        1 : "#ffffff" ,
        2 : "#00C300" ,
        3 : "#000000" ,
        4 : "#33485B"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run the Flask server loop in a child thread and set `use_reloader = False`:

```py
try
    ...
    from threading import Thread
    ...
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
    exit(0)

class WebServerCreationClass:
    def __init__(self):
        ...

        @self.flaskServer.route('/')
        def ClickEventButton():
            newText = self.textToTemplate.get(1.0 , END)
            return f"{newText}"

        def FlaskHandler():
            try:
                self.flaskServer.debug = True
                self.flaskServer.run(
                    host = "0.0.0.0" ,
                    port = 8080,
                    use_reloader = False
                )
            except Exception as ex:
                print(ex)

        def ButtonEventClicker():
            Thread(target=FlaskHandler, daemon=True).start()

        ...
```